# How to group by and count distinct occurences of values in a particular column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an SQL query I'm trying to translate into R:

```
SELECT t."col1", t."col2", count(DISTINCT t."date")
FROM t
GROUP BY t."col1", t."col2"
```

where the R data frame looks something like this:

```
col1 col2 date
a 1 2016-01-09
a 1 2016-01-02
a 1 2016-01-02
b 1 2016-01-07
b 1 2016-01-03
b 1 2016-01-02
b 1 2016-01-07
b 2 2016-01-11
```

The actual output should be something like this:

```
col1 col2 count
a 1 2
b 1 3
b 2 1
```

I've looked at the count method in the plyr package... but it doesn't take into account the number of distinct dates.

Runinng this

```
count(t, c("col1", "col2"))
```

produces this:

```
col1 col2 count
a 1 3
b 1 4
b 2 1
```

How can I replicate the behavior of the SQL query in R?

Comment: Using base R I would go with `aggregate(date ~., unique(df), length)`. But there are many other ways. If you want plyr, you could probably do `count(unique(df), c("col1", "col2"))` (though I don't have it installed). Not sure why you thought your solution will work if you are not specifying you want unique entries anywhere in your code

Comment: look at the `sqldf` package.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the atomic level data in a data frame called df:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(col_1, col_2) %>%
  summarise(distinct_ct = n_distinct(date))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(distinct_ct = uniqueN(date)), by = .(col_1, col_2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame is named `df`, then:

```
aggregate(df, date ~ ., function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  col1 col2 date
1    a    1    2
2    b    1    3
3    b    2    1
```